# Do I need the old private key to generate new Distribution Certificate?

Tags: iphone

My distribution certificate is going to expire in few days. I have changed my system so I want to know that do I need the old private key to create new certificate signing requrest?

Also I wanted to know that is is necessary to use the same email ID that is used to create the developer account while creating new certificate signing request?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its already expired, don't worry about old certificates.
Else you need to export your private keys on your old system and then install your private key and profiles on your new machine.

I think its not mandatory to use same email ID to create new certificates.

Comment: what if i dont have access to old system.. means what if i formatted that system and dont have backup of private keys?

Answer (score 1):

No you do not have to know anything about your previous keys to generate new ones. Just follow the instructions in the portal, and generate new ones.